# optimized join query with 3 tables

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

i have 3 tables

```
user1[user1_id,name], 

user2[user2_id, user1_id], 

user3[user3_id,user1_id]
```

my 1st query is

```
select a.user1_id, b.user2_id, c.user3_id from user1 a   
left join user2 b on b.user1_id = a.user1_id
left join user3 c on c.user1_id = a.user1_id

my second query is

select a.user1_id, b.user1_id from user2 a
left join user3 b on b.user1_id = a.user1_id
```

i used this all query.

my question is how to i optimized my query or optimized the query time because when i used this two query the query time is 15.767s with 18592 return values. can someone correct my query or it is the table design.

Comment: use the first select query c.user1_id is done, why if you go with second query.

Comment: Have you tried adding indexes to the columns you're joining?

Comment: i try second query for another testing.

Answer (score 1):

Basically you should

a) add indexes on the columns

```
CREATE INDEX IDX_USER1_USERID ON USER1(USER_ID); 
CREATE INDEX IDX_USER2_USERID ON USER2(USER_ID); 
CREATE INDEX IDX_USER3_USERID ON USER3(USER_ID);
```

this will drastically reduce query times

b) Reduce the resultset aka the amount of transport data

The user ID is always the same. Don't select it thrice and reduce the transport data to 1/3rd.